# Springboot jolt custom transformation missing springboot context

Tags: spring-boot, jolt

I have following xml file from where I need to transform few properties. when I try to inject bean in `CountryListBean` in `CountryCodeTransformer` it does not instantiate as I suspect JOLT custom transformation missing the SpringBoot context while performing transformation.

any clue how to carry-forward SpringBoot context so that jolt custom transformer can get injected bean properly

- sample xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CountryList xmlns="http://www.org.com/tc/CountryList">
  <countries>
    <countryName>Afghanistan</countryName>
    <eCountryName>Afghanistan</eCountryName>
    <twoCharCode>AF</twoCharCode>
    <threeCharCode>AFG</threeCharCode>
  </countries>
  <countries>
    <countryName>Albania</countryName>
    <eCountryName>Albania</eCountryName>
    <twoCharCode>AL</twoCharCode>
    <threeCharCode>ALB</threeCharCode>
  </countries>
</CountryList>
```

- xsd for above xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="http://www.org.com/tc/CountryList"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="CountryList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="countries">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="countryName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="eCountryName"
                type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="twoCharCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="threeCharCode" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

- model class for bean

```java
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.org.xsd.CountryList.Countries;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CountryListBean {

    private Map<String, Countries> countryToCode;
}
```

- Springboot bean configuration

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.org.CountryListBean;

import com.org.xsd.CountryList.Countries;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamReadException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LookUpListConfigurtion {

    @Bean
    public CountryListBean countryConfiguration() {

        InputStream is = LookUpListConfigurtion.class.getResourceAsStream("/mapping/CountryList.xml");

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        List<Countries> countries = null;
        try {
            countries = xmlMapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<Countries>>() {
            });
        } catch (StreamReadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DatabindException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<String, Countries> nameToCountry = countries.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Countries::getECountryName, Function.identity()));

        CountryListBean bean = new CountryListBean();
        bean.setCountryToCode(nameToCountry);

        return bean;
    }

}
```

- Jolt transformer

```java
public class CountryCodeTransformer {

    

    @Component
    public static final class countryCode extends ListFunction {
    @Autowired
    CountryListBean bean;
        @Override
        protected Optional<Object> applyList(List<Object> arg0) {

            return Optional.of(String.valueOf(bean.getCountryToCode().get(arg0.get(0)).getTwoCharCode()));
        }

    }

}
```

- transformer specs

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.ContextualTransform;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.SpecDriven;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.Optional;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.tree.MatchedElement;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.common.tree.WalkedPath;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.SpecException;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.modifier.OpMode;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.modifier.TemplatrSpecBuilder;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.modifier.function.Function;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.modifier.spec.ModifierCompositeSpec;

public class CountryTransformerSpec implements SpecDriven, ContextualTransform {
    private static final Map<String, Function> STOCK_FUNCTIONS = Map.of(
            "countryCode", new CountryCodeTransformer.countryCode());

    private final ModifierCompositeSpec rootSpec;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private CountryTransformerSpec(Object spec, OpMode opMode, Map<String, Function> functionsMap) {
        if (spec == null) {
            throw new SpecException(opMode.name() + " expected a spec of Map type, got 'null'.");
        }

        if (!(spec instanceof Map)) {
            throw new SpecException(
                    opMode.name() + " expected a spec of Map type, got " + spec.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        if (functionsMap == null || functionsMap.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SpecException(opMode.name() + " expected a populated functions' map type, got "
                    + (functionsMap == null ? "null" : "empty"));
        }

        functionsMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(functionsMap);
        TemplatrSpecBuilder templatrSpecBuilder = new TemplatrSpecBuilder(opMode, functionsMap);

        rootSpec = new ModifierCompositeSpec(ROOT_KEY, (Map<String, Object>) spec, opMode, templatrSpecBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public Object transform(final Object input, final Map<String, Object> context) {

        Map<String, Object> contextWrapper = new HashMap<>();
        contextWrapper.put(ROOT_KEY, context);

        MatchedElement rootLpe = new MatchedElement(ROOT_KEY);
        WalkedPath walkedPath = new WalkedPath();
        walkedPath.add(input, rootLpe);

        rootSpec.apply(ROOT_KEY, Optional.of(input), walkedPath, null, contextWrapper);

        return input;
    }

    /**
     * This variant of modifier creates the key/index is missing, and overwrites the
     * value if present
     */
    public static final class Overwritr extends CountryTransformerSpec {

        public Overwritr(Object spec) {
            this(spec, STOCK_FUNCTIONS);
        }

        public Overwritr(Object spec, Map<String, Function> functionsMap) {
            super(spec, OpMode.OVERWRITR, functionsMap);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This variant of modifier only writes when the key/index is missing
     */
    public static final class Definr extends CountryTransformerSpec {

        public Definr(final Object spec) {
            this(spec, STOCK_FUNCTIONS);
        }

        public Definr(Object spec, Map<String, Function> functionsMap) {
            super(spec, OpMode.DEFINER, functionsMap);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This variant of modifier only writes when the key/index is missing or the
     * value is null
     */
    public static class Defaultr extends CountryTransformerSpec {

        public Defaultr(final Object spec) {
            this(spec, STOCK_FUNCTIONS);
        }

        public Defaultr(Object spec, Map<String, Function> functionsMap) {
            super(spec, OpMode.DEFAULTR, functionsMap);
        }
    }
}
```

- sample json

```json
{
  countryName: 'Afghanistan'
}
```

- Expected json

```json
{
  countryName: 'AF'
}
```

- jolt specification

```json
[
  {
     "operation": "com.org.jolt.transformer.CountryTransformerSpec$Overwritr",
     "spec": {
          "countryName": "=countryCode(@(1,countryName) ))"     
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: any help from experts?